# In Flex / AIR: Is it possible to detect the size of a removable volume?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I'm writing an application in AS3 on Flex that utilises USB removable storage - SD cards -  and I need to display the space available on it in a progress bar.

Getting the space available on a drive is straightforward enough using:

*`flash.filesystem.storageVolume.rootDirectory().spaceAvailable`*

..but to display free space graphically, I need to know the total size of the drive and I can't find anyway of getting that info.

For now, I've resorted to guessing the size roughly based on the free space, but this is obviously far from ideal.

I've scoured the vast documentation that Adobe provides and googled 'til my fingers ache, but no luck.

I'm guessing this may not be possible with the standard framework and may require a custom Native extention to be written - please tell me I'm wrong :)

Answer (score 4):

I think the only way this is possible is to recursively scan directories, which may consume an extensive amount of time for complex file systems.

```
import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.system.Capabilities;

private function getDrives():void
{
     var os:String = Capabilities.os.substr(0, 3).toLowerCase();
     var currentDrives:Array = (os=="mac") ? new File('/Volumes/').getDirectoryListing() : File.getRootDirectories() ;
     for each(var file:File in currentDrives){
         trace ("Drive: " + file.name + " Size: " + file.size);
     }
}
```

Or, a different approach:

```
import flash.filesystem.StorageVolume;

var volumes:Vector.<StorageVolume> = StorageVolumeInfo.storageVolumeInfo.getStorageVolumes();
for each (var volume:StorageVolume in volumes)
{
    // use isRemovable property for USB:
    if (volume.isRemovable && volume.isWritable)
        trace("Drive: " + volume.drive + " Size: " + volume.rootDirectory.size);
}
```

Then, recursively scan using a function like:

```
public function getDirectorySize(path:Array):Number
{
    var size:Number = new Number();
    for (var i:int = 0; i < path.length; i++)
    {
        if (File(path[i]).isDirectory)
            size += getDirectorySize(File(path[i]).getDirectoryListing());
        else
            size += File(path[i]).size;
    }
    return size;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I did consider scanning the file system to get the "used" space value.. Doesn't matter if it's not absolutely accurate, an approximation will do just fine. I will try it and let you know how it works out. Thanks again!

Comment: You could recursively scan asynchronously using getDirectoryListingAsync, in which you could immediately visualize space available while updating space used as totals become available.  Sorry, this would make a great feature request at Adobe.

Comment: I imagine scanning the entire disk is going to take quite a bit of time, my guess is you're going to better off checking the OS and using built in command line tools to get back the information you need.  For windows you can use this: dir C:\|find /i "bytes free" > drivespacefree.txt, for *nix systems you can use df http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/check-free-space/ you can use either bash in *nix as a native process to run the command line tools and cmd.exe in C:\windows\system32\ on windows systems.